# Insert data In normalized Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have a normalised database,

```
Students (RollNo, Name) - e.g. (1, "John")
Books (BookCode, Name) - e.g. (1, "StoryBook"), (2, "Dictionary")
Loans (RollNo, BookCode) - e.g. (1, 2)
```

Now that "john" wants to loan "Dictianry"; But I can't insert ("john", "Dictionary") into the Loans table,
 because it needs the BookID and RollNo.

My backend FW restricts me to a single query per Request.

Is there any way to do this in one sql Statement without first looking up the ID's for books and insert (with two separate SQLs)?

Comment: Hmm this case seems a little strange? How do you know john wants to buy the dictionary but not the ids of john and the dictionary? You shouldnt work with the names but always with the ids.

Comment: You've said normalized table.. But it sounds like this is not a NORMALIZED as you've said. we can consider this as Bad table construction.

Comment: Case: lets say this is a website where somebody can buy books. When user john logs in, instead of only storing his name in a session. Also store his Id. Same goes for the form that lets him loan a book. Instead of only submitting the name of the book, also send the id of the book. There is no case where you want to select the id by name. What if there are 3 johns? Always use the unique index for storing stuff

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub query, but that seems a bit complex just for an insert. You could change the primary keys to `Name` instead of `RollNo` and `BookCode` but that is bad practice.

To get around it you could try to cache students and books. It seems strange that you are limited to one query per request, maybe you should focus on that?

Answer (score 0):

try this i think it will work in your case

```
insert into Loans (RollNo, BookCode)
    select s.RollNo,b.BookCode from Students s
    full join Books b on 0=0
    where s.Name='John' and b.Name='Dictionary'
```

Comment: FULL JOIN isn't valid MySQL syntax i think you mean CROSS JOIN here? 0=0 is also wierd JOIN operating what is always true.